# How do I adjust the system settings to allow more simulated devices to boot at once?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator, xcode9

I got the following error message when trying to boot my fourth simulator:

> #### Unable to boot device due to insufficient system resources.
>
> Please see Simulator Help for information on adjusting system settings to allow more simulated devices to boot at once.
>
> maxUserProcs: 709, runningUserProcs: 569, enforcedProcBuffer: 144

I don't know what Simulator Help they are referring to, because I'm not finding anything about this. Google also doesn't help me. It's pretty clear from the error message that if `runningUserProcs` + `enforcedProcBuffer` is greater than `maxUserProcs`, you cannot boot another simulator. What isn't clear is how to change the `maxUserProcs` setting.

Does anyone know how I can change the `maxUserProcs`?

Comment: https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/9.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev8a5f2aa4e

Comment: Thanks @dan. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks @dan. That is worked for me. Force quit simulator and run again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
sudo launchctl limit maxproc 2000 2500
```

Source: https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/9.0/index.html#/dev8a5f2aa4e

Comment: Also note that beginning with macOS 10.14 we auto-scale these values to the amount of system RAM, so an iMac Pro with 64 GB of memory should have a higher default limit.

Comment: @russbishop "Unable to boot device due to insufficient system resources." error came up. I quit all the apps. and then tried to open up the simulator. Still the same issue. Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: This worked for me. However I only got 8GB....so I don't know how much an impact this will have on my macbook M1.

Answer (score 1):

This pointer helped me, though, when I run this particular command given above

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 2000 unlimited
```

it sets my setting as `maxfiles    2000           10240`

So I run again this bit different one

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000
```

and it now the setting got set as `maxfiles    65536          200000`

And doing this later one only helped me to re run the simulator again successfully. I have a Mojave 10.14.5.